# Save and Update in two databases?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In a project EF6 is used. Now on a later stage there is requirement to use tables from an another database.

DAL is implemented using `Generic Repository` and `Unit of Work`

I'm wondering is there a way in DbContext to refer two separate databases? Also how EF will know which entity belongs to which database.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's not possible to use EF in such way.

Instead create a view referencing a table in another database and map that view.